# Can't make conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have Header component which I would like to use in multiple screens with multiple use cases such as in MainScreen I want to show only profile icon whereas in other screens I would like to use both backButton and profile icon.

I get `isProfileIconVisible` and `isBackButtonIconVisible` from props in Header Component.

```
        this.state = {
            isProfileIconVisible: props.isProfileIconVisible,
            isBackButtonIconVisible: props.isBackButtonIconVisible
        }
```

I have rendering functions.

```
    _renderProfileIcon () {
        let profileIcon = (
        <View style={styles.profileButtonContainer} >
            <CustomIconButton
                onPress={this.props.onProfilePress}
            ></CustomIconButton>
        </View>
        );
        return profileIcon;
    };

    _renderBackButtonIcon () {
        let backButonIcon = (
        <View style={styles.backButtonContainer} >
            <CustomIconButton
                onPress={this.props.onBackPress}
                iconName={"arrow-left"}
            ></CustomIconButton>
        </View>
        );
        return backButonIcon;
    };
```

and in main render function I am making conditional rendering:

```
    render() {
        const { style, isBackButtonIconVisible, isProfileIconVisible, ...otherProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {isBackButtonIconVisible ? this._renderBackButtonIcon : null}
                <View style={styles.textContainer} >
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                </View>
                {isProfileIconVisible ? this._renderProfileIcon : null}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

with this setup, I am not able to render either ProfileIcon nor BackButtonIcon.
I got the `text` prop but not icons.

Header Component `propTypes` and `defaultProps`:

```
Header.propTypes = {
    onBackPress: PropTypes.func,
    onProfilePress: PropTypes.func,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    backButtonIconName: PropTypes.string,
    isProfileIconVisible: PropTypes.bool,
    isBackButtonIconVisible: PropTypes.bool,
};
Header.defaultProps = {
    backButtonIconName: 'keyboard-backspace',
    isProfileIconVisible: true,
    isBackButtonIconVisible: true,
}
```

And this is how I call Header component from another component:

```
        <Header
            text={"Welcome!"}
            isProfileIconVisible={true}
            isBackButtonIconVisible={false}
            onProfilePress={this.handleProfileButtonPress}
            style={styles.headerContainer}
          />
```

Can you help me where I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_renderBackButtonIcon` and `_renderProfileIcon` are **functions**, you need to call them to get their return values:

```
render() {
    const { style, isBackButtonIconVisible, isProfileIconVisible, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {isBackButtonIconVisible ? this._renderBackButtonIcon() : null}
            <View style={styles.textContainer} >
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
            </View>
            {isProfileIconVisible ? this._renderProfileIcon() : null}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Note the `()` after `this._renderBackButtonIcon` and `this._renderProfileIcon`.

---

Side note: There's no reason to have `...otherProps` here:

```
const { style, isBackButtonIconVisible, isProfileIconVisible, ...otherProps } = this.props;
```

You never use it.

There *is* an argument for adding `text` to that list and using it, rather than `this.props.text` within the return value:

```
render() {
    const { style, isBackButtonIconVisible, isProfileIconVisible, text } = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {isBackButtonIconVisible ? this._renderBackButtonIcon() : null}
            <View style={styles.textContainer} >
                <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
            </View>
            {isProfileIconVisible ? this._renderProfileIcon() : null}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, those little parentheses fixed the problem. ```...otherProps ```  was there only for experimental purposes. you were right i never used it.